# Access control from its event handler

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to access a control's parameters inside it's event handler without mentioning its name.

An example makes it clear:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    self.text="clicked";//pseudo code
}
```

I want somthing like this which would change the text of label1 to "clicked" or whatever I want.

I want to do this because the software I'm making consists of large number of labels and textboxes
and I prefer to just copy and paste the single code in each event handler rather than typing seperate one for each control.

Can something like this be done in C#? I am using winforms.

Comment: Cast the sender as `Label`. You're done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `sender` parameter (in pretty much all events in Windows Forms) is actually a reference to the control which fired the event.

In other words, you can simply cast it to a `Control` (or `Label`, or whatever):

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      var ctrl = sender as Control; // or (Control)sender
      ctrl.Text = "clicked";
}
```

This allows you to attach the same handler method to events on multiple controls, and differentiate them using the `sender` parameter:

```
// the `label_Click` method gets called when you click on each of these controls
label1.Click += label_Click;
label2.Click += label_Click;
label3.Click += label_Click;
```

Another way to do this, if you want to avoid casting altogether, might be to use a lambda to capture the parent control:

```
label1.Click += (sender, args) => label1.Text = "Clicked";
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `sender` argument:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label self = (Label)sender;
    self.text = "clicked"; //pseudo code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the sender argument:

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label clickedLabel = sender as Label;
    if(clickedLabel == null)
        return;
    clickedLabel.Text = "clicked"; //pseudo code
}
```

to slow :(