# Disable Parent Control of a button in windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

so what i want to do is, on Event ButtonClick disable parent Control of this button.
In my Form i have several Panel's in which those button actually are.

I am using following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Control control = button1.Parent;
   control.Enabled = false;
}
```

This xode is working fine, but I wanted to use `this.Parent` instead of `button1.Parent`, so that each button would be able to disable its own parent `Panel`(in this case will disabled Panel of `button1`).

When i am using `this.Parent` I get a `System.NullReferenceException`.

Knows some one why i am getting this error ?

Comment: Yes, `Form.Parent == null`, right? Do you want `(sender as Control)?.Parent?.Enabled = false;` ? Or `sender as Button` to filter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access control from its event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949056/access-control-from-its-event-handler)

Comment: `this` is the class inside which the code resides, most likely the form in your case and of course it doesn't have a Parent. - Note that when you disable the Panel the nested controls, ie the Button will be disabled as well. Is that what you want?

Comment: You can combine below answers to get this working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is your current class you want to use the `sender` and cast it to `Control` than get it's parent something like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var uc = sender as Control;
    uc.Parent.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: @Tarik I've skipped that part the Op shoud do something like you have done in your answer (therefore your answer is more complete than mine)

Comment: @TaW actually is declared there `var uc = sender as UserControl;`

Comment: Sure. But what in the OP makes you think a UC is (or should be) involved??

Comment: Ah you are right i meant `Control` since `UserControl` is the base class for WPF not winforms

Answer (score 0):

`this` represents the Window, which has no Parent.

You can do the following:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    Control control = ((Button) sender).Parent;
    control.Enabled = false;
}

Button[] buttons = {button, button2....};
foreach (Button button in buttons)
    button.Click += button_Click;
```

Alternatively, you can create a class inheriting from Button. You can then add a Click event handler that disables it's parent control. You can then use this button instead of the default one.

Comment: if you do this you will block only the `button1. Parent`